# iCloud Drive for Windows sync is slow. Can I manually copy files from a Mac?

Tags: icloud, windows

I have an hybrid network with both Macs and PCs. I use iCloud as my main cloud storage, because my family smartphones are Apple's.

Anyway, I'm always struggling with their Windows sync tool. It's extremely slow, hangs frequently and doesn't look reliable at all (I'm coming from years of Dropbox and the comparison is embarrassing: but again, since the tight integration with iPhones and iPads, I'm willing to suffer a bit).

Now, I have a large amount of files I need to download on one Windows machine but it's taking ages. It doesn't look like it can pull data from a locally available Mac, so everything is getting downloaded.

I wonder if it's safe to stop the service, manually copy my files from network, restart the sync service: is it smart enough to see those files as already available?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. I need to download about 100gb of files to a new Windows machine and it's been 7 days so far and looks like not even half of files are donwloaded. This is a piece of crap software

Comment: @delphirules I had to give up, rarely I've seen a software as bad as iCloud for Windows. I'm implementing a custom solution, with Windows machines using OneDrive, Mac machines using iCloud and FreeFileSync to bridge them. A pity, but it is what it is.

Comment: Same here, i've moved to Dropbox and downgraded my Icloud plan to the minimum i need to keep my Iphone backups.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of weeks trying to fix it, after trying get support from Apple with no luck, after seeing a lot of people with the same issue and no way out, i've found the solution :

Move to Dropbox.